# Trying to get child of ListView with ContainerFromIndex() returns null

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to check a checkbox in my ListView:

```
Grid specialGrid = (Grid) listView1.ContainerFromIndex(index);
CheckBox specialBox = (CheckBox) specialGrid.FindName("Special");
specialBox.IsChecked = true;

<ListView x:Name="listView1">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
            <Grid x:Name="LineW">
                <CheckBox x:Name="Special" Grid.Column="1" Checked="Special_Checked" Unchecked="Special_Unchecked"/>
```

This is essentialy my ListView. But calling ContainerFromIndex() returns null, even though the item exists (as long as I remove the cause of the crash, of course) I don't understand what is going wrong. I have tried calling

```
int number = listView1.Items.Count;
```

before this, and for some reason it returns 0. But I did add content to the ObservableCollection, and if I remove the code that causes the crash it shows up properly.

Edit: I have experimented some more, and it seems like the view is not rendered at the time that I am trying to access it. But if I wait and add it later, it can bug if someone clicks on a checkbox before the times is done. Is there a way to do it immediately after the view had been calculated, but before it can be interacted with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your ObservableCollection to ItemSource property of your listview. x:Name with in Template cannot be accessed.  have a look at example below

```
    /*Xaml Code*/
     <Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind items,Mode=OneWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind is_checked}"></CheckBox>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind text}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>    
//C# code
namespace App1
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        ObservableCollection<Item> items;
        public MainPage()
        {
            items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            items.Add(new Item() { is_checked = true, text = "item1" });
            items.Add(new Item() { is_checked = true, text = "item2" });
            items.Add(new Item() { is_checked = false, text = "item3" });
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }


    }
    public class Item
    {
      public   bool is_checked { get; set; }
      public  string text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Edit**
To fetch an item with particular text use LINQ. Check the sample code below

```
public Int32 getindexofitem()
{
  var index = items.IndexOf(items.Single(g => g.text == "item2"));
  return index;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try when I am at home. Why does the Mode need to be OneWay? This would mean that ticking the CheckBox doesn't change the OberservableCollection?

Comment: Actually itemsource has to be oneway but is_checked and text must be Twoway for the changes to reflect in collection. I will edit now

Comment: I get the following error: XLS0414 The type 'local:Item' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Comment: Have you created your class named **Item** and placed in same namespace??

Comment: public class Item Yes I did, I copy-pasted it. And it is in the same namespace (x:Class="Test.MainPage" and namespace Test). I also get the errors The namespace prefix "local" is not defined. 
Item is not supported in a Windows Universal project.

Comment: i have edited now you can see i have included xmlns:local="your namespace". in my case it is ** xmlns:local="using:App1"**

Comment: **Item** is just a class defined by us. Above sample is done in windows unversal project only it works perfectly fine.

Comment: It works, but how can I get the index at which a specific string is located at? I can't do 
    " items.Remove(new Item() { is_checked = true, text = textToDelete });
    items.Remove(new Item() { is_checked = false, text = textToDelete }); " to remove both possibilites, wheter it is checked nor unchecked.

Comment: To Fetch index for particular item i have added an edit